# Game fails to check condition and starts in the background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, countdown

***Functionality:***

User will navigate from the "Instruction" Page (1st Page) to the "Game" Page (2nd Page) and play the game designed. "Instruction" Page has a list of instructions for users and a start button that when clicked will navigate users to the "Game" page. "Game" Page has got a fade-in countdown counter, purpose is to notify users that game will start in x seconds, after which game will start. 
Hence, fade-in countdown counter will only start when users are in the "Game" page, before the commencement of the game.

***Issues:***

The fade-in counter starts even before users are navigated to the "Game" page. Therefore, when users are still in the 1st page: "Introduction Page", the fade-in counter in the 2nd page: "Game" page will start to run.

**What it should have been:**

The above issue stated shouldn't be happening, the fade-in counter in the 2nd page should only start countdown only when user has navigated from the 1st page to the 2nd page.

**What has been done:**

I have set each page as `z-index`, hence, the 1st page is set as `z-index=1` while the 2nd page is set as `z-index=2`, furthermore, I have set the 2nd page to be `display:none`, hence the 2nd page will only be displayed when called.

Furthermore, I have declare a global boolean variable `var booleanplay== true`, and within my `<script>`, I have set the conditional check to call on the game() functionality. Hence, rightfully, it should have checked on the condition before it runs the method.

I have attached the code for your perusal..please help. I am totally at wits end.

**Code:**

```js
function Page2() {
    var BooleanPlay = true;

    $("#page1").hide();
    $("#page2").show();
    //To check if the game is being played, will call MainGame method, else wouldnt start MaiinGame and reset counter and speedto original value
    if (BooleanPlay == true) {
        console.log("Game Reset");
        rollingInterval = setInterval(updateTimer, 20000);
        clearInterval(rollingInterval);
    }

}


var count = 5;

//Fade-in Countdown counter function
function updateTimer() {
    if (count > 0) {
        $("#content").fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $("#content").text(count);
            $("#content").fadeIn();
            count--;
        });
    } else if (count == 0) {
        $("#content").fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $("#content").text("Start!!");
            $("#content").fadeIn();
            count--;
            // after the fade-in counter, will call the mainGame() function
            MainGame();
            console.log("MainGame()");
        });
    } else {
        $("#content").fadeOut();
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    updateTimer()
}, 2000)

    function MainGame() {
        var numOfSpin = 0,
            distanceCovered = 0,
            counter = 0,
            timer = 10;

        $("#scrollerDiv").scroll(function () {
            var height = $("#scrollerDiv").scrollTop();
            for (var i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
                if (height > i * 10) {
                    if (i >= 0 && i < 10) {
                        $("#roller").attr("src", "Image/Rolling_pin/rolling pin_0000" + i + ".png");
                    }
                    if (i >= 10 && i < 100) {
                        $("#roller").attr("src", "Image/Rolling_pin/rolling pin_000" + i + ".png");
                    }
                    if (i >= 100 && i < 1000) {
                        $("#roller").attr("src", "Image/Rolling_pin/rolling pin_00" + i + ".png");
                        $("#scrollerDiv").scrollTop(0);
                        numOfSpin++;
                        distanceCovered += 0.59;
                        console.log(distanceCovered);
                        console.log(numOfSpin);
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        rollingInterval = setInterval(function () {
            console.log("rollingInterval");
            counter = counter + 1;
            timer = timer - 1;
            speed = distanceCovered / counter;
            speed2dec = speed.toFixed(2);
            //document.getElementById("speedSpan").innerHTML = speed2dec + "<br/>"+"ms";
            $('#speedSpan').html(speed2dec + '<br>ms');
            //document.getElementById("timeSpan").innerHTML = timer + "s"
            $('#timeSpan').html(timer + ' s');

            if (counter == 10 && speed > 20) {
                console.log("Count");
                clearInterval(rollingInterval);
                $("#page2").hide();
                $("#page3").show();
            } else if (counter == 10 && speed < 20) {
                numOfSpin = 0;
                distanceCovered = 0;
                counter = 0;
                timer = 10;
                $("#page2").hide();
                $("#GameOver").show();
                //clearInterval(rollingInterval);
            }
        }, 1000)
    }
```

```css
#page1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#page2 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
#scrollerDiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1150px;
    left: 200px;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 650px;
    width: 750px;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="page1" align="center" style="background-image: url(Image/Page1.png); width:100%; height:100%;">
    <input style="outline:0;height:90px;width:400px; margin-top:1300px" type="image" id="Point" src="Image/Click_to_start_button.png" onclick="Page2()" />
</div>
<div id="page2" class="img-wrapper" align="center" style=" position: relative; background-image: url(Image/Page2.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; width: 100%;height: 100%;">
    <div id='content'></div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    <canvas id="Counter" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    <p id="speedSpan">0.00
        <br>ms</p>
    <p id="timeSpan">10 s</p>
    <img id="roller" style="position: absolute; top:470px; left: 0px; width: 100%" src="Image/Rolling_pin/rolling%20pin_00000.png" />
    <img id="scroll" style="position:absolute; top: 1250px; left: 380px; overflow-y: auto;" src="Image/Scroll.png">
    <div id="scrollerDiv">
        <p id="invisibleElement"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

where you're defining `interval` is starting the timer. So you'll need to move the assignment of the `interval` timer, to whatever method triggers your page depth reshuffle (i.e. `page2()` method). So that when you switch pages it starts the timer.

Update:

The line:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  updateTimer()
}, 2000)
```

initialises the variable `interval` and assigns it the setInterval timer. This starts the timer, hence why the game countdown begins as soon as the page loads.

I would change it to be:

```
var interval;
```

and then move the setInterval assignment into the `page2()` function

```
function page2(){

    interval = var interval = setInterval(function() {
        updateTimer()
    }, 2000);
    $("#page1").hide();
    $("#page2").show();
    .....
```

Comment: do you mean the `var interval = setInterval(function(){updateTimer()},2000)`?? what do you mean by the assignment of the timer, which one are you referring to?? Then what about the boolean check conditions in the `function page2()`?? apologies, if i sound noob

Comment: the boolean in page2() does nothing to stop the timer which is already started and calls updateTImer() which starts the game

Comment: also that `BooleanPlay` is pointless as it will always be true when it is checked in the if below, and as far as I can see it isn't used anywhere else.

Comment: Hence, I can say that `BooleanPlay` can just be deleted??May I ask another question, what will happen if users were to be re-directed back to the game page for a re-try? Meaning, after the game, users who fail will be directed to the game over page and then back to the instruction page then to the game page. The following syntax does not seem to work well.

Comment: yes `BooleanPlay` can be removed safely.  Not sure what you mean about 'the following syntax does not seem to work well'..? What syntax?

Comment: following syntax as in:`interval = setInterval(function() {updateTimer()}, 2000); `. Or do I need to set some conditional checks when users are being navigated back to gamepage after they have failed the initial game. Hence, the flow: instruction-> game-> gameover-> instruction->game. The current  code of `interval = var interval = setInterval(function() {updateTimer()}, 2000);` works for the initial round of instruction-> game but if I were to set the same function of stopping the gametime before the user re-enters the game page, do I need to set a conditional check?

Comment: right I see what you mean now. You will need to call `clearInterval(interval)` to stop the previous timer before assigning the new timer. So yes you will need a boolean if statement like `if(playerFailed){...` and in there clear the old timer.

Comment: so that means that  i will need to add `clearInterval(interval)` within the boolean condition statement?? furthermore, I will need to set my boolean if statement within the function page2() right?? will I also need to add in the `interval=  setInterval(function() {updateTimer()}, 2000);` within the boolean condition?

Comment: Yes, you would put the fail check bool in the page2() function and put the clearInterval inside the fail bool check. If you could upvote and accept my also also that would be great ;)